# Tomcat startup (default web.xml) issue

Tags: xml, tomcat, webserver, boot

Similar topics have been made, but nothing spot on. Therefor, a title that reminds of some others.

I've been trying to get Tomcat running, which suceeded, but it certainly won't show me nothing. I get a 404 when I try to enter.

Catalina logs gives the following output:

```
SEVERE: Parse error in default web.xml
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: XML document structures must start and end within the same entity.

[Loads of stuff like "at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1642)"]
23-Feb-2012 07:59:26 org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig processDefaultWebConfig
SEVERE: Occurred at line 1210 column 1
23-Feb-2012 07:59:26 org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig start
SEVERE: Marking this application unavailable due to previous error(s)
23-Feb-2012 07:59:26 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Error getConfigured
23-Feb-2012 07:59:26 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Context [/skat] startup failed due to previous errors
23-Feb-2012 07:59:26 org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol start
INFO: Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
23-Feb-2012 07:59:26 org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol start
INFO: Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8443
23-Feb-2012 07:59:26 org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 509 ms
```

Also, I won't paste 1200 lines, but my default web.xml would look like this:
http://pastebin.com/mXSy6TPK

It should have 1209 lines, but when I posted it, I accidentally removed a new line space.
As you see in the error message, the error occurs at a line that isn't even there.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You did not close the root element. Do not tamper with the default web.xml unless you know what you are doing.